# Not able to download patch SUPEE 5994

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, download

Where can I download the patch SUPEE 5994 for release 1.9.1.1 for Community Edition. Tried searching on the net and it directs me to https://magento.com/tech-resources/download. However I am not able to find the download links. Will be great if somebody could direct me to the right url.
Regards,
Joye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That page does seem to be broken right now.

A mirror of the patch can be found here

https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-patches/blob/master/EE1.9/PATCH_SUPEE-5994_EE_1.9.0.0_to_EE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-05-15-02-38-58.sh

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. There are quite some patches in this repository...Not able to find 5994 for community edition.

Comment: The patch i linked to covers the 1.9 series, even though it says `EE` in the title. There is no 1.9 EE series of magento.